# Cannot read property 'property' of null

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have a question regarding vanilla JavaScript, and what is the best practice to get rid of an error in console, saying that certain element doesn't exist on a page.

To be more precise, I made a custom slider, for my Homepage. And that slider only exists in index.html. And, whenever I go to other pages, I get an error, saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

Now, I know what the problem is, JS is looking for a certain class, and the class doesn't exist on that page. So, my question is, what is the best practice to overcome this problem?

Do I put it in a "for" loop, and if so, over what do I loop?

Comment: Post your HTML//

Comment: I think I was very specific. 
It's not a code problem, per se, but a "what is the best course of action" kind of thing. 

There's a JS code, that is looking for a certain block of code, that isn't on the other pages. So, my question was: what to do in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an if condition to search for the slider and only run the code if that is found.

Something like this:

```
if(document.getElementById("slider") != null)
{
 //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice. And, of course, it did the trick. 

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to handle this kind of issue is to wrap the relevant block of code in a `try catch` and then handle the error however you want in the catch.

You could also wrap the code that tries to read the style in an `if` block to check that the element exists.

These are both just good practices in your code in general when dealing with things that are potentially unknown, but really best practice is to only load in the script that handles the slider when your's on index.html and not other pages.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the suggestion. I gotta say, I haven't worked with "tray catch" yet, but, I'll sure look it up now 